# Getting the current week using T-SQL Using Parameters

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

I want to have a function within the SQL query which will bring out the current week in SSRS 2005 using parameters. I have declared two variables @FromDate and @ToDate. I am using these two variables in the where clause below

```
where SH.[] between CONVERT(datetime, @FromDate, 105) and CONVERT(datetime, @ToDate, 105)
```

How do I bring out the current week using @FromDat and @ToDate? Can I have any help?

Thankss

Comment: Clarify your question. What do you mean under "current week"? If I look at calendar - I see right now current week is 52 week of 2014 year. But it is so without any relevance to your `@FromDate` and `@ToDate` - so what do you want to achieve by using that parameters?

Comment: There's this SSRS report that needs to be delivered to someone which will have the current week's sales. Hence, the FromDate abd ToDate @AndyKorneyev

Comment: It is still doesn't clarify what do you mean by current week. And your comment looks truncated.

Comment: @Andy is right, do you mean to be able to pass in the parameters from (today's date) to (end of the week date) ?? If that is the case, then you're defining when you want the end of the week to be :) since you have a FROM and TO !

Comment: @AndyKorneyev I want the report to be delivered once a week with the sales from Monday to Friday in the current week. DOes that make it clearer?

Comment: @ClaudiovYes thats what I mean. How do I do that function? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
          CREATE TABLE dbo.TestDates (
            SaleID TINYINT IDENTITY(1,1),
            Amount NUMERIC(9,2),
            SaleDate DATETIME
            );

            GO

            INSERT INTO dbo.TestDates (Amount, SaleDate)
            VALUES (200.00, '2014-12-15'),
            (130.00, '2014-12-16'),
            (40.00, '2014-12-17'),
            (70.00, '2014-12-18'),
            (590.00, '2014-12-19')



            -----------------------------------------
 CREATE FUNCTION dbo.uspGetCurrentWeek(@From VARCHAR(100)
 RETURNS VARCHAR(100)

 AS

 BEGIN

DECLARE @StartCounter TINYINT = 1
DECLARE @EndCounter TINYINT = 5

     WHILE @StartCounter <= @EndCounter
         BEGIN

  DECLARE @String VARCHAR(100) = ( SELECT 'Week' +
                                        CAST(DATEPART(WEEK, SaleDate) AS VARCHAR(2))
                                         FROM dbo.TestDates
                 WHERE SaleDate = @From )
        SET @StartCounter = @StartCounter +1
                       END
              RETURN @String
      END
            --------------

            -----Test data ----
            SELECT *, dbo.uspGetCurrentWeek('2014-12-15')
            FROM dbo.TestDates;
            ---------------------------------
```

Comment: Can I not implement the DateAdd part in the WHERE clause?

Comment: @MohamedFareedh - I updated my answer, this solution will do it for you. You can even specify a Week number in the function !

Comment: @MohamedFareedh To make it even more automated, I removed the input parameter for Week number, it will pick it up by itself using the DATEPART() function.  Good luck and Merry Christmas !  :)